# I made some customization in Zoho CRM module and now I want to reuse these customization in another Zoho CRM

Tags: functional-programming, crm, zoho

I made some customization in my demo Zoho CRM module and now I want to reuse these customization in my original Zoho CRM.

Can I export or publish these customization from my demo Zoho CRM and import in my original Zoho CRM?

If yes then guide me to export & import these customization in between to different Zoho CRM accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create solution in your demo Zoho CRM module. Add your customization related changes in that solution. You can export that solution from demo Zoho CRM module and import same solution to original Zoho CRM.

Comment: I want to export/import my Custom function, Web Hooks & Rules and not the data from modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can not export rules, triggers, alerts. Simply you can not export automation work, but if there is custom functions you can just copy/paste it and apply the same rules from existing crm. You can only export modules from CRM, By export module meaning module fields and data to file.